# Android Compose - How to make TabBar collapse along with TopAppBar

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, view, android-jetpack-compose

I want to have an appbar in the top of my screen which have two lines:

1. The top line will contain screen name and navigation icons (TopAppBar)
2. The second line will contain tabs to navigate to other parts of the application (TabBar)

I wish to implement the above in a scaffold.  Following is the code I have written so far.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class, ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun NestedScrollTest() {

    val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.exitUntilCollapsedScrollBehavior(rememberTopAppBarState())
    Scaffold(
        modifier = Modifier.nestedScroll(scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection),
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                title = { Text(text = "Scroll Behavior Test") },
                navigationIcon = {
                    IconButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                        Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Menu, contentDescription = "")
                    }
                },
                scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior
            )
        }
    ) {
        MyTabRowNew()
        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(top = it.calculateTopPadding() + 56.dp)) {
            items((1..50).toList()) { item ->
                Text(modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp), text = "Item $item")
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyTabRowNew(){
    var state by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    val titles = listOf("Tab 1", "Tab 2", "Tab 3 with lots of text")
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 64.dp)
    ) {
        TabRow(selectedTabIndex = state) {
            titles.forEachIndexed { index, title ->
                Tab(
                    selected = state == index,
                    onClick = { state = index },
                    text = { Text(text = title, maxLines = 2, overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis) }
                )
            }
        }
    
    }
}
```

With this code, the TopAppBar collapses, but the TabBar does not and so looks odd
How can I collapse TabBar too along with TopAppBar, when I scroll in LazyColumn.

Thanks

Comment: When do you want them to collapse is it when you scroll down?

Comment: Yes.   I want them to collapse when I scroll down in lazy column.  Can it be done?

Comment: i hope you this is what your looking for if yes accept the answer so that anyone whos looking for the same thing would find it

Comment: @Ayman Ait
Thanks.I worked very well.  

One issue I noticed is that the TopAppBar's feature of changing surface elevation color while scrolling is not working now. Would we be able to add this feature too for both TopAppBar and TabRow?

Comment: Furthermore, When I scroll, the contents of TopAppBar slide to the left and back  while the bar is collapsing, while the TabRow slides up and down along with the content.  Is it possible for both to have same behaviors'?

Comment: you can customize the behavior of the AnimateVisibility check out this: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation/composables-modifiers#animatedvisibility

Comment: Ok...finally I got what I needed.  Thanks Ayman Ali.

Comment: @Ayman Ait
I just noticed that with animated visibility, the movement of collapsing of the bars is not aligned with the scrolling action. I use Exit vertically and Enter vertically, but they move at different "speed' compared to scrolling "speed".  Any way I can align the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually acheive this with a combination of LazyColumnState and AnimateVisibility.
first you need to add this Composable function in your project somewhere:

```
@Composable
    fun LazyListState.isScrollingUp(): Boolean {
        var previousIndex by remember(this) { mutableStateOf(firstVisibleItemIndex) }
        var previousScrollOffset by remember(this) { mutableStateOf(firstVisibleItemScrollOffset) }
        return remember(this) {
            derivedStateOf {
                if (previousIndex != firstVisibleItemIndex) {
                    previousIndex > firstVisibleItemIndex
                } else {
                    previousScrollOffset >= firstVisibleItemScrollOffset
                }.also {
                    previousIndex = firstVisibleItemIndex
                    previousScrollOffset = firstVisibleItemScrollOffset
                }
            }
        }.value
    }
```

what this does it simply detects if the LazyColumn is being scrolled up .
now that you have this its simple you just need to detect if the LazyColumn is being Scrolled up if True show the TopBars if not hide them:

```
val lazyColumnState = rememberLazyListState()
                    Scaffold(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                        topBar = {
                            AnimatedVisibility(visible = lazyColumnState.isScrollingUp()) {
                                TopAppBar(
                                    title = { Text(text = "Scroll Behavior Test") },
                                    navigationIcon = {
                                        IconButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                                            Icon(
                                                imageVector = Icons.Default.Menu,
                                                contentDescription = ""
                                            )
                                        }
                                    }
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    ) { paddingValues ->
                        //second top bar
                        Column(modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize()
                            .padding(paddingValues)) {


                            AnimatedVisibility(visible = lazyColumnState.isScrollingUp()) {
                                Row(
                                    modifier = Modifier
                                        .fillMaxWidth()
                                        .height(40.dp)
                                ) {
                                    Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }, colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(containerColor = Color.Red)) {
                                        Text(text = "5")
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            LazyColumn(
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .fillMaxSize() ,
                                state = lazyColumnState
                            ) {
                                items(50) {
                                    Text(
                                        text = it.toString(), modifier = Modifier
                                            .fillMaxWidth()
                                            .height(30.dp)
                                    )
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```